# Sorting large files in better time than 0(n log n) time

Tags: c++, sorting, file-handling

I have two files:

One file stores  name "mapping.txt" of 10GB:

```
1 "First string"
2 "Second string"
3 "Third string"
...
199000000 "199000000th string"
```

And the other file stores integers from mapping.txt in some arbitrary order (stored in file.txt):

```
88 76 23  1  5 7 9 10 78 12 99  12  15  16 77  89  90  51
```

Now I want to sort "mapping.txt" in the order specified by the integers above like:

```
88 "88th string"
76 "76th string"
23 "23rd string"
1  "1st string"
5  "5th string"
7  "7th string"
```

How do I accomplish this using C++?

I know that for every integer in the file one can perform a binary search in "mapping.txt", but since its time complexity is `O(n log n)`, it is not very efficient for large files.

I'd like a way to do this that is more performant than `0(n log n)`.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such. The meta discussion about whether this question should stay open is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183985/regarding-closure-of-questions-as-not-real-questions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that for every integer in file.txt one can perform a binary search in "mapping.txt"

As you said binary search is not useful here, besides the reason that you exposed you also have the challenge that mapping.txt is not in a friendly format to perform searching or indexing.

If possible I would recommend to change the format of the mapping file to one more suitable to do direct seek calls. For instance, you could think in a file containing fixed length strings so you can calculate the position of each entry ( that would be constant in the number of fseek calls but keep in mind that the function itself wouldn't be constant)

[EDIT]:

Other thing you could do to minimize access to the mapping.txt is the following:

- Load the "order" file into an array in memory but in a way where the position is the actual line on mapping.txt and the element is the desired position on the new file, for instance the first element of that array would be 4 because 1 is on the 4th position (in your example).
- For convenience split the new array into N buckets files so if an element would go to the 200th position that would be the first position on the 4th bucket (for example).
- Now you can access the mapping file in a sequential fashion, you would for each line check on your array for the actual position in your new file and put then in the corresponding bucket.
- Once you passed the whole mapping file (you only have to checked it once), you only need to append the N buckets into your desired file.

Comment: @RoseBeck If you can't change the mapping file format then go with Sebastian advice, I don't think you have too many options anyway due to the format of that mapping file.

Comment: I really did not understand. Can you please explain the 2nd point in detail?

Comment: @RoseBeck Ok... Imagine that you reversed the problem. Instead of accesing the "order" file once and the mapping several we would be doing the opposite. Due to that we will have an element on mapping that will be located in some position in the new file. Since your strings are not length-fixed, put them in their new position in a new big file would be inefficient. To avoid that you will be splitting that huge file in several small ones. For example, a string that would be in the 134th position will be stored in the 34th position of the 100-200.txt file.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I would do. This may not be the most efficient way, but I can't think of a better one.

First, you pass over the big file once to build an index of the offset at which each line starts. This index should fit into memory, if your lines are long enough.

Then you pass over the small file, read each index, jump to the corresponding location in the big file, and copy that line to the target file.

Because your index is continuous and indexed by integer, lookup is constant time. Any in-memory lookup time will be completely overshadowed by disk seek time anyway, though.

Answer (score 2):

As Sebastian suggested, try

1. creating an index over the mapping file ("mapping.txt") with the offset (and optionally length) of each string in the file.
2. Then access that index for each entry in the ordering file ("file.txt") and seek to the stored position in the text file.

This has linear time complexity depending on the size of the two files and linear space complexity with small factor depending on the line count of "mapping.txt"

For fast and memory-efficient sequential read access to large regular files use `mmap(2)` and `madvise(2)` or their corresponding constructs in the Windows API. If the file is larger than your address space, mmap it in chunks as large as possible. Don't forget to madvise the kernel on the different access pattern in step 2 (random vs. sequential).

Please don't copy that much stuff from a file onto the heap, if you don't need it later and your system has memory maps!

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a list of exactly how you want the data output, I'd try an array

Comment: But since I have a large file of 10GB. So I can not store that in memory..so can u pls explain ur answer..as to how will it fit in memory

Comment: for file.txt. And a line number.

Comment: Can u pls explain with code...i am getting confused..since "strings that I hav are of arbitrary length"

Comment: File 1: each line consists of a number and a string.
File 2: List of lines from file 1 you want to output.
So you read file 2 and then read file 1 and output the string with a number that matches one of your entries in the array from file 2

Answer (score 1):

You would be best served to split this problem up into smaller problems:

- Split mapping.txt and file.txt into `n` and `m` entry chunks respectively (`n` and `m` could be the same size or different)
- Take your normal map-sorting routine and modify it to take a chunk number (the chunk being which `m`-offset of file.txt you're operating on) and perform the map-sorting on those indices from the various mapping.txt chunks.
- Once complete, you will have `m` output-X.txt files which you can merge into your actual output file.

Since your data is ASCII, it will be a pain to map fixed windows into either file thus splitting both into smaller files will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good candidate for mergesort.
This will be O(n log n) but most algorithms will not beat that.
You just need to use the index file to alter the key comparison. 
You will find merge sort in any decent algorithms text book and it is well sort to doing a external sort to disk, for whne the file to be sorted is bigger than memory.

If you really must beat O(n log n), pass over a the file and build a hash table, indexed by the key, of where every line is. Then read the index file and and use the hash table to locate each line. 
In theory this would be O(n + big constant). 
I see some problems with this however: what is n? that will be a big hash table. Implementation may very well slower than the O(n log n) solution due to "big constant" being really big. Even if you mmap the file for effienct access you may get a lot of paging.

Comment: I was thinking on the same thing, there is a challenge though, since there is a mapping that has to be done and there is not guaranteed that a subset of both file would contain that match.